# Как установить новые сети в Windows общедоступными?

Tags: windows, сеть, cmd, powershell

Суть такова подключаю телефон на андроиде как USB-модем, создается новая сеть в настройках адаптера, как сделать так что-бы эта новая сеть сразу "делилась" интернетом на мою локальную сеть (LAN) Ethernet (на роутер короче), что-бы не лазить постоянно в свойства и ставить галку? Может использовать скрипт на PowerShell или bat. А можно использовать сценарий PowerShell или bat который будет это делать, MAC устройства известен или его просто в исключения добавить?

Comment: В какие свойства Вы лазите и какую галку ставите? Если при подключении телефона и создании новой сети генерируется event, то можно создать задачу, испольняемую по этому event'у. А уж что туда записать - будет зависеть от Вашего ответа на мой вопрос. :)

Answer (score 0):

Не претендуя на правильный ответ просто оставлю это как заметку, т.к. в комментарий текст не влазит.

Лично мне надо было направить трафик к определенному хосту именно через модем. Сделал это, настроив триггер от источника NetworkProfile на событие с номером 10000.
Привожу как пример часть кода, где ищется Id сетевого соединения для USB-модема, который работает как RNDIS-интерфейс. Используется утилита **wmic** и найденное значение записывается в **idx**.
А дальше можно уже делать, что хочешь.

```
@rem ============ Variable description ==============
@set  mdm=RNDIS
@rem ============ Script =======================
@for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== usebackq" %%i in (`@wmic nic where NetConnectionID^='%mdm%' get Index /value ^|@find "Index"`) do @set idx=%%j
@if "%idx%" equ "" exit /b 1
```

Но я считаю, что лучше всего подойдет решение на Powershell. Batch уже устарел, хотя и им можно выполнить автоконфигурацию сетевого интерфейса.